# Не подключается class в img

Tags: css, jquery

День добрый! Ребята можете разъяснить почему не подключается класс в данном коде:

```html
<img
    src="http://tricolor.utest.space/assets/images/like_dislike/like.png"
    alt="like"
    data-article="<?php echo $information_id?>"
    id="likeBtn"
    name="like"
    <?php echo (isset($_COOKIE["article-$information_id"]) && $_COOKIE["article-$information_id"] == 'likes') ? 'class=\'actionBtn\'' : '';?>
>
```

Ну суть такова что через jquery добавляем класс `actionBtn` - он добавляется все норм. вот только стиль не работает... Почему???

css:

```
#likeBtn, #dislikeBtn {
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 42px;
}
#likeBtn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#dislikeBtn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.actionBtn {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

jquery:

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
$('#likeBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var article_id = $(this).data('article');

    $.ajax({
        url:'route=like/like/index',
        type: 'get',
        data:{type: 'likes', article_id:article_id},
        success: function (data) {
            if(data){
                $('#likeBtn').addClass(data);
                $('#dislikeBtn').removeClass(data);
            }else{
                $('#likeBtn').removeClass('actionBtn');
            }
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
});
$('#dislikeBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var article_id = $(this).data('article');

    $.ajax({
        url:'route=like/like/index',
        type: 'get',
        data:{type: 'dislikes', article_id: article_id},
        success: function (data) {
            if(data){
                $('#dislikeBtn').addClass(data);
                $('#likeBtn').removeClass(data);
            }else{
                $('#dislikeBtn').removeClass('actionBtn');
            }
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: дайте код `jquery` скрипта добавления, ну и `css`

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#likeBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var article_id = $(this).data('article');
        $.ajax({
            url:'route=like/like/index',
            type: 'get',
            data:{type: 'likes', article_id:article_id},
            success: function (data) {
                if(data){
                    $('#likeBtn').addClass(data);
                    $('#dislikeBtn').removeClass(data);
                }else{
                    $('#likeBtn').removeClass('actionBtn');
                }
            },...`

Comment: #likeBtn, #dislikeBtn {
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 42px;
}

#likeBtn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


#dislikeBtn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.actionBtn {
    background-color: blue;
}

Comment: нажмите `править` под своим вопросом, и добавьте в вопрос ваш код...не возможно же читать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что элементу так же назначаются стили по `id`-селектору, вес которого выше, чем `class`. Почитайте об этом на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), чтоб лучше понимать, что происходит.

```css
#id-1 {
    background: none;
}

.class-1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="id-1" class="class-1">div 1</div>
<div class="class-1">div 2</div>
```

Comment: Ну  так и предполагал..спасибо..

Comment: Подскажи, решением может быть перенос стилей с ID на class??

Comment: @VetalSlepak решений может быть много, в плоть до прописывания наиболее приоритетных стилей в атрибуте `style`. Вопрос в том, что в итоге вам нужно и почему вы решили манипулировать стилями.

Comment: x-foby спасибо огромное!!Все получилось..решил сделать через атрибут style.. Еще раз спасибо за помощь

Comment: @VetalSlepak отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный - это даст другим участникам понять, что вопрос решён и закрыт)